# Is it possible to 'instantly' create arbitrary files?

Tags: unix, dd

I've seen the following trick to create large, empty files somewhat quickly:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.dat bs=1024 count=1024
```

However, this still takes some time when creating multi-GB files. I presume this time is dominated by the disk writing all the `\0`s from `/dev/zero` to `test.dat`.

Is there any way to "instantly" create a file of arbitrary size, without actually initializing its contents to anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, if your filesystem supports [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).

Your `dd` method actually creates the files and **fills** the created file with zero's. It actually has to write those zeros and that takes time.

If you 'skip' ahead in the file without writing you will still create a seemingly large file, without actually writing to the file. Since this large file does not consume actually disk space it is even possible to create files larger than the FS it is on allows.

If you want to try this, use something like this
`dd seek=123456 if=/dev/null of=sparse-file bs=1M`

(Take care with backups and restores with software which is unaware of sparse files).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Unfortunately, my Mac doesn't seem to support sparse files, and the file seems to still be filled with ``\0``s. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: If the file is sparse and you **read** it you are supposed to get \0's.  Note that my example used `/dev/null` and not `/dev/zero`. It did not write any zeros.

Comment: Hmm, I should have read that wikipedia article more thoroughly. I missed the part where is mentions: " Most modern file systems support sparse files, including most Unix variants and NTFS, **but notably not Apple's HFS+.** "

Comment: Sorry for the confusion -- my point is that the file creation time isn't any faster if I use the seek option to dd, it still takes several seconds per GB. Like you mention, Apple's filesystem doesn't seem to take advantage of the seek option