# Filling /var parition

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to ‘instantly’ create arbitrary files?](https://superuser.com/questions/458722/is-it-possible-to-instantly-create-arbitrary-files)

I work on Linux centos. I want to fill the /var partition to check the system behavior.
What is a quick way to fill the partition ? The /var is around 20GB and I want to fill around 18GB.

Answer (score 0):

> dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat bs=1G count=18

your block size is 1GB and you write 18 blocks

Comment: I don't think that `count=0` will copy anything?

Comment: @NikosC. I'll just simplify it.